# IOS to calling function giving giving error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a `MTBBarcodeScanner` [interface](https://github.com/mikebuss/MTBBarcodeScanner/blob/develop/Classes/ios/Scanners/MTBBarcodeScanner.m) to implement a barcode scanner application.
I need to get the still image of the scanner in my code, so I am trying to call the function:

```
- (void)captureStillImage:(void (^)(UIImage *image, NSError *error))captureBlock {

    if ([self isCapturingStillImage]) {
        if (captureBlock) {
            NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kErrorDomain
                                                 code:kErrorCodeStillImageCaptureInProgress
                                             userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"Still image capture is already in progress. Check with isCapturingStillImage"}];
            captureBlock(nil, error);
        }
        return;
    }

    AVCaptureConnection *stillConnection = [self.stillImageOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    if (stillConnection == nil) {
        if (captureBlock) {
            NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kErrorDomain
                                                 code:kErrorCodeSessionIsClosed
                                             userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"AVCaptureConnection is closed"}];
            captureBlock(nil, error);
        }
        return;
    }

    [self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:stillConnection
                                                       completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
                                                           if (error) {
                                                               captureBlock(nil, error);
                                                               return;
                                                           }

                                                           NSData *jpegData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
                                                           UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:jpegData];
                                                           if (captureBlock) {
                                                               captureBlock(image, nil);
                                                           }

                                                       }];

}
```

From my viewcontroller I am calling this function like:

```
 UIImage *img;
 NSError *e;
 [_scanner captureStillImage:img :e];
```

but giving me the error:

> No visible @interface for 'MTBBarcodeScanner' declares the selector 'captureStillImage::

How can I call this function my `UIViewcontroller` subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your block is incorrect. It should be the following:

```
[_scanner captureStillImage:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Also, this is a callback function, you are not supposed to feed parameters into it, these are being returned from it.

If you would like to have variables representing the return values of the callback function outside you callback, you need to declare `__block` variables.

```
__block UIImage* img;
__block NSError* e;

[_scanner captureStillImage:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
     img = image;
     e = error;
}];
```